# How to run while loop in the background

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to program a turn-based game where some things take more than one turn to happen. I figured out that putting a while loop inside the function that makes the action that takes some turns could work. This is my test:

```
#This function is supposed to 'work' after 3 turns
def action(current_turn):
    while global_turn - current_turn != 3:
        pass
    test = "works"

test = "doesn't work"
game =True
global_turn = 0
while game:
    global_turn += 1
    print(f'\nThis is turn #{global_turn}\n')
    user_input = input('Do [1]yes [2]no')
    if user_input == '2':
        pass
    elif user_input == '1':
        action(global_turn)
```

I thought this would have kept on printing "This is turn #{global_turn}" forever, even if I called the function but it just sits there. Is there any way to make the while loop keep on while also proceeding with the outside loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
#This function is supposed to 'work' after 3 turns
def action(current_turn, action_turn):
    if global_turn != action_turn:
        return
    print('action!')

game = True
global_turn = 0
action_turn = None
while game:
    global_turn += 1
    print(f'\nThis is turn #{global_turn}\n')
    user_input = input('Do [1]yes [2]no')
    if user_input == '2':
        pass
    elif user_input == '1':
        action_turn = global_turn + 3
    action(global_turn, action_turn)
```

**Note:** this does not actually run a while loop in the background. In your example it does not seem necessary. But if your game becomes more complex you might want to look into

- [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)
- [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)
- [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

to run things in the background.

---

**EDIT**

An [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) version:

```
import asyncio


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.game_running = True
        self.global_turn = 0
        self.turn_started = asyncio.Event()
        self.turn_ended = asyncio.Event()

    async def action(self, wait_turns):
        while wait_turns > 0:
            await self.turn_ended.wait()
            await self.turn_started.wait()
            wait_turns -= 1
        print('action!')


    async def main(self):
        while self.game_running:
            self.global_turn += 1
            print(f'\nThis is turn #{self.global_turn}\n')
            self.turn_ended.clear()
            self.turn_started.set()
            await asyncio.sleep(0)  # yield control to other tasks
            user_input = input('Do [1]yes [2]no')
            if user_input == '2':
                pass
            elif user_input == '1':
                asyncio.ensure_future(self.action(3))
            self.turn_started.clear()
            self.turn_ended.set()
            await asyncio.sleep(0)  # yield control to other tasks


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game();
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(game.main())
```

**Explanation:**

- When the user inputs `1` the `action` coroutine is scheduled in the "background" using [`asyncio.ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future)
- With each turn two [`asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) signals are set. One for a turn start, one for the turn end.
- The `action` coroutine waits for a defined number of turns to start and end before it prints "action"
- The `action` coroutine can run several times in the background, each counting down the number of turns until becoming active.
- `await asyncio.sleep(0)` is required for the `action` coroutines to continue running.
- If you need actions to be active while the `main` function is waiting for user input you can use [`aioconsole.ainput`](https://aioconsole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

  ```
  from aioconsole import ainput

  async def main(self):
      [...]
      user_input = await ainput("Do [1]yes [2]no")
      [...]
  ```

Comment: The thing is in my game there are 3 player and you can make multiple actions in a turn.

Comment: @bajotupie I added another solution to my answer